# Exchangeable fields in SQL index

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I m designing a table for a list of chats. Every chat references two users and must be unique per given user pair. Evidently, a user pair is symmetric for permutations: it does not matter, which user in a pair comes first and which one comes second.

Suppose a user table has an integer **UserID** as PK. Then chat table will have a pair of FK fields: **UserID1, UserID2**. I want that every pair of users have a unique record in chats table. Then I can create unique **INDEX(UserID1, UserID2)**. However, this index will not be unique in terms of a user pair because it may include also permutations when UserID2 comes first: **(UserID1, UserID2)** and **(UserID2, UserID1)** will be two distinct different pairs, while by required logic, they should be treated one distinct record.

Is there a way to implement this construct in pure SQL without external coding, such as DB triggers or scripting? I m using MS SQL Server for prototyping. But I want to have a design universal and neutral as possible to be compatible with most SQL compliant databases. It is mere a question on optimal architecture than on specific SQL implementation code as such.

Possible ideas:

1. Make and index on a hash of ordered user pairs
2. Check user order and put a user with smaller ID first in all queries

But all these put restrictions on external queries outside of SQL.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm confused. How do you want to solve this problem without "putting restrictions on external queries"? You explicitly want to forbid them from duplicating pairs. That's observable no matter how you do it. (Both options seem like reasonable approaches to me.)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: Thank you for the feedback. What I m planning so far, is just restricting inserts and selects to only ordered pairs where smaller user ID comes first and explicitly reorder, if an order of pair is inverse. But it is an external code control, not intrinsic to DB design itself. It looks a little ugly solution, so I wonder, if some pure SQL canonical design exists for such cases.

Comment: A `CHECK` constraint on the table *is* intrinsic to the database itself: `CHECK (UserID1 <= UserID2)`. But that still requires clients to know that the database wants the pairs this way. I can't think of any table design that can reflect an unordered binary relationship "naturally" without any constraints or triggers. (Personally I'd just hide this behind a stored procedure, but that's because "pure SQL" is simply not a concern where I live.)